# Get lines between two timestamps from a file

Tags: files, awk, date, timestamps, time

I have this large file that I need to go through using date and time.
Every line in this file has a date and time in it.

I need to search through the lines and get the lines that lie between two specific dates and times.

Example file (the field for date and time is $2 and $3):

```
SERVER 2015-12-12 05:00:20 some_text_here something  
SERVER 2015-11-02 12:22:40 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-12-11 20:00:00 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-12-11 23:00:00 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-12-12 00:30:00 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-12-12 00:59:00 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-09-20 03:28:11 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-04-16 04:49:59 some_text_here something
```

The command I tried (users have to supply 4 arguments when running the script):

```
AAA="$1 $2"
BBB="$3 $4"

awk '$2" "$3>="'"$AAA"'" && $2" "$3<="'"$BBB"'"' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

I am using the lines above as a script but its not working.

`newfile.txt` should contain (using arguments `2015-12-11 20:00:00 2015-12-12 01:00:00`):

```
SERVER 2015-12-11 20:00:00 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-12-11 23:00:00 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-12-12 00:30:00 some_text_here something
SERVER 2015-12-12 00:59:00 some_text_here something
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Can you also tell us which lines you want to see in `newfile.txt` and which lines you do see in `newfile.txt`?

Comment: i should be able to copy the whole line that satisfy the condition (date/time)

Comment: I think no line does match the condition because even for the first line the time is after the BBB time and for all other lines the date is before the AAA date.

Comment: im not exactly sure what you mean, but I just put the sample file there for reference. The actual file contain thousands of line. and the AAA should be "earlier" than BBB

Comment: I think in your example lines the command should not print any lines to `newfile.txt` as none of *these* lines satisfies the condition. Or which of this lines satisfies the condition in your opinion (please tell me the line or line number from you example above)?

Comment: I think your edit no. 6 is not helping any. The fact that it is in the script doesn't change anything in this case. And also since you removed the exmple dates we can no longer see why the result in the example should be like this. I suggest you undo the edit no. 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need a script that you can input the two specific dates and times.
[image]

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 4 ];then
exit 0
fi
AAA=$1" "$2
BBB=$3" "$4
awk -v begintime="${AAA}" -v endtime="${BBB}" '$2" "$3>=begintime && $2" "$3<=endtime' exa > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The only real problem is that you assign to `$AAA` and `$BBB` instead of `AAA` and `BBB`. So if you do (nearly the same as your code):

```
AAA="2015-12-11 20:00:00"
BBB="2015-12-12 01:00:00"
awk '$2" "$3>="'"$AAA"'" && $2" "$3<="'"$BBB"'"' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

it should already work. But I recommend the following further changes in order to reduce potentioal quoting problems (especially if you happen to reuse this apprach somewhere else or put special chars in `AAA` or `BBB`):

```
AAA="2015-12-11 20:00:00"
BBB="2015-12-12 01:00:00"
awk -v string1="$AAA" -v string2="$BBB" '$2" "$3>=string1 && $2" "$3<=string2' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

You can read about `-v` in the man page of `awk`.

Comment: apologies. i missed that. that should really be without `$`. also, added some details

Answer (score -1):

`awk` is not the best tool.

```
sed -e  "/^$AAA/,/^$BBB/,p" file.txt
```

and `man sed`.

Comment: I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 46: unknown command: \`,'`. You have to remove the second comma.

Comment: This is only would be correct if the file is sorted. But the example above is not sorted (even though the result is correct in this case).

Comment: I just saw that the command is *not correct at all* because it uses the `^` anchor and doesn't exclude unmatched lines with `-n`.